# Normalize column that contains a date MATLAB

Tags: math, matlab

I want to normalize a matrix, but if a column contains dates moth/day/year, how can I normalize, is it better to get rid of it?

Comment: What would a normalized date look like?

Comment: yeah, same question, better get rid of it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, consider:

```
> datestr(datenum(2011, 2, 28, 1, 2, 3))
ans= 28-Feb-2011 01:02:03
> datestr(floor(3600* datenum(2011, 2, 28, 1, 2, 3))/ 3600)
ans= 28-Feb-2011 01:02:00
```

So, now based on `datenum` you may 'normalize' as it suits best for you.